# Session variables reset on the refresh of the page (logging out user)

Tags: php, authentication, session-variables

I am using a PHP authentication system to log in users.  Logging in users works fine, however, upon refreshing the page (on any page) the session variables reset and the user is "logged out".  I am using session_start() on every page.  I have the files auth.php and authenticate.php to log and authenticate users.  This has been a frustrating problem and help will be appreciated.  I will give you the code here:

auth.php:

```
<?php
function credentials_valid($email, $password) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `salt`, `password` 
              FROM `#######` 
              WHERE `email` = '$email' ";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $password_requested = sha1($user['salt'] . $password);
        if($password_requested === $user['password'])   {
            return $user['id'];
            }   
        }
    return false;
}

//logs into the user $user
function log_in($user_id){
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

}

//Returns the currently logged in user (if any)
function current_user(){
    static $current_user;
    if(!$current_user) {
        if($_SESSION['user_id']){
            $user_id = intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
            $query = "SELECT * 
                         FROM `#######` 
                         WHERE `id` = $user_id";

            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
                $current_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                return $current_user;
                }
            }
        }
        return $current_user;
    }


//Requires a current user
function require_login() {
    if(!current_user()){
        $_SESSION['redirect_to'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit("You must log in.");

}
}

?>
```

authenticate.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "database.php";
db_connect();
require_once "auth.php";


$user_id = credentials_valid($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
if($user_id){
    log_in($user_id);

    if($_SESSION['redirect_to']){
        header("Location: " . $_SESSION['redirect_to']);
        unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);

    }else{
        header("Location: index.php");          
    }

}else{
        header("Location: login.php?error=1");
        exit("You are being redirected");       
}

?>
```

on one of my pages where a user is logged in, i have this in the php header:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once "database.php";
    db_connect();
    require_once "auth.php";

    $current_user = current_user();

if(isset($_GET["logout"]) && $_GET["logout"]==1)
    {
        //User clicked logout button, distroy all session variables.
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: '.$return_url);
    }
?>
```

The system is erratic.  Sometimes if I refresh the page right after a login, the session variables will be destroyed right away.  Other times, the user will stay logged in after several refreshes in a row.  Please let me know what issues you see.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Kindly note the important points to use session_start() on every page of PHP Code and from your code it seems that some of the pages doesn't include the session_start();

Another thing that your code:

```
    header("Location: " . $_SESSION['redirect_to']);
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);
```

must be change your code as:

```
    a=$_SESSION['redirect_to'];
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_to']);
    header("Location: " . $a);
    exit();
```

un-setting the after the redirection is not recommended and also you have to close the earlier process and it sometimes continue to run the process in background. What every you try after header command is not recommended..

Comment: ok, after a certain amount of time (even with these changes and adding session_start() to auth.php), the session variable is reset

Comment: @user1072337 check the PHP value of session time validity